# Dell R630 boots into kernel panic on newer kernel version

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, dell

Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell R630

Booting `4.4.0-116-generic` from the base install:

1. Warning of "read or write outside of disk `hd0'"
2. System manages to boot just fine.

Booting `4.4.0-165-generic` from system update:

1. Warning of "invalid extent"
2. System starts to boot but then fails into a stack trace.

Before this, I was in a state where none of the kernels available on the system (165 and a few earlier) could boot the system, so I reinstalled Ubuntu.

The disk layout:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x92b9e484

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T 83 Linux
```

This is via the Ubuntu installer, but I don't bother with a swap partition.

I wonder if Dell has a bug whereby the BIOS can't boot a kernel unless it is close to the start of the disk, and I need to do a `/boot` partition. I really hope this is NOT the case, because I have a few systems now built in this manner and I am scared to reboot.

I have tried updating the BIOS.

Here's the kernel panic:
[image: Kernel Panic]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved, but I am not sure which action caused the resolution.

Per Dell Support, I hooked up the iDRAC, and updated the iDRAC and PERC firmware. The new kernel booted to panic.

I booted the old kernel, in order that it ensure the filesystem was properly FSCKed.

Meanwhile, I had googled the stack trace a bit, and per [this Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31141/5571), I added in for good measure:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.4.0-165-generic
sudo update-grub
```

The system boots to the new kernel now.

I have a few similar systems, and if I can determine which combination of firmware updates / `update-initramfs` is the best solution, I will update my answer.