# Accidentally I broken my system. Kernel Panic! VFS unable to mount root fs

Tags: boot, kernel, grubrescue, initramfs, 21.10

I'm on Ubuntu Impish Indri 21.10. after Upgrade Ubuntu Hirsuite Hippo 21.04 to Impish Indri 21.10, i get Kernel Panic when i boot the Ubuntu after i accidentally force `do-release-upgrade`

[image]

I tried to boot my old kernel but the boot is stuck on Automatic Report like below :

[image]

**What did i tried**

1. I tried this thread of [VFS Issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/41939/856659!), when i run this and reboot.

   `sudo update-initramfs -u -k version sudo update-grub`

   my both kernel and the recovery mode are stuck on Kernel Panic! VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0).
2. I tried to switch to TTY on GRUB

   `Linux ... ro quiet splash 3`
   `Linux ... ro nomodeset init=/bin/bash`

   after i into the boot still Stuck on Kernel Panic.
3. I remembered i have 1000 more packages upgradable. so i plug LiveUSB and run:

   `sudo fdisk -l`
   `sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt`
   `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
   `sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts`
   `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
   `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
   `sudo chroot /mnt`
   `apt update && apt upgrade`
   `update-initramfs -u -k version`
   `update-grub`

   after reboot, the boot still stuck on Kernel Panic.

**Possible my main problem**
i see on error output above at line:

> VFS: Cannot open root device "/dev/sda7" or unknown-block(0.0)

after i checked on `grub.cfg`, their have different paramaters on `--set-root` and `root=uuid=`.

**My partition** :

- /dev/sda1 #/boot
- /dev/sda5 #/swap
- /dev/sda6 #/tmp
- /dev/sda7 #/

Well, What is the correct "root=" boot option to be?

**My Kernel** :

- Linux 5.4.0-90-generic
- Linux 5.4.0-84-generic

Please rescue my kernel.

Comment: What machine are you on and does it boot to grub?

Comment: @darth_epoxy i'm on Intel Celeron 1.89GHZ Gnome 3.26.1. no it doesn't, it boot into kernel

Comment: Can you find a solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268512/kernel-panic-on-boot-after-upgrade-to-20-04-1 or in this older less conclusive thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183069/dell-r630-boots-into-kernel-panic-on-newer-kernel-version

Comment: @darth_epoxy that's difference thread, i can try it

Comment: Consider reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch. It would be faster.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi it's my last step, but i don't want to lose my data.

Comment: You can boot Ubuntu from a live session, and take a backup of the data with it. In case you already have data in the root partition, copy it to an external hard disk/other partitions. While installing Ubuntu should only touch the root partition (ensure that you **do not** erase the whole disk while installing Ubuntu).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i can reinstall my root partition, but it will back to 17.10 version and i need to more time to upgrade 21.10

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri You can temporarily install 17.10, then use it to download 21.10, and finally fresh install 21.10 (instead of upgrading).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i'm really frustation after i tried install new kernel 5.15 and 5.16 on https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa:mainline . i decided to reinstall OS but my root partition is including my /home. that's absolutly erase my data.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Boot from a live CD, and either back up the important data from your home to an external hard disc or, copy the important data from home to another partition (where you would not install Ubuntu, so that it would remain intact).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks in advance, i'm already on 18.04 LTS stable and i have been upgraded to 21.10 on kernel of 5.13. should i install linux-image-unsigned 5.16?